# Cookies permission in Chrome extension doesn't work

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I'm having problem with my Chrome extension when I try adding cookies permission.
First, the manifest file is like this

```
"permissions": [
    "cookies",
    "https://api.box.com/*", 
    "https://www.box.com/api/*",
    "https://dl.boxcloud.com/*",
    "tabs",
    "identity",
  ],
```

But when I click to the permission properties of my extension in chrome://extensions/, there is no `cookies` permission showing up. I'm not sure whether it is problematic or not, please help me clarify.

The main problem is, when I run the code:

```
getCookies("https://www.box.com", "tokens", function(tokens){
        console.log("Token returned");     
});

function getCookies(domain, name, callback) {
    console.log("Getting cookies...");
    chrome.cookies.get({"url": domain, "name": name}, function(cookie) {
        if(callback){
            console.log("Done getting cookies, calling back...");                    
            callback(cookie.value);
        }
    });
}
```

The `callback` function is never called, thus the `Token returned` message is never printed. I could see the `"Done getting cookies, calling back..` message in the console. So why is this happening? Please help me resolve it...

Comment: Try amending your permissions to `"https://www.box.com/*"` and check returned `cookie` for `null`.

Comment: @Xan Thanks, that works. Both the `null` and the permission are source of the problem. Please move your comment to the answer so I can close the question :)

Comment: `cookies` is a [permission that doesn't cause warnings](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permission_warnings#nowarning) which is why you don't see it on the permissions list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with the code:

1. If a cookie is not found, `chrome.cookies.get` callback is called with `cookie == null`.

   Therefore, calling `callback(cookie.value)` is an error and doesn't get executed.
2. The cookie is not found, because the URL you're passing, `https://www.box.com`, does not match the permission pattern `"https://www.box.com/api/*"`. You need to either change the pattern or the URL you're passing to `chrome.cookies.get`.